# The "contact us" link is hidden behind a "sign up" banner for people who don't have accounts

Tags: bug, design, welcoming

I was testing something in as an unregistered user and spotted that the "contact us" link is hidden behind the "sign up" banner:

[image]

Can the link be moved to the top of the "Company" list? People shouldn't have to go hunting around for this sort of thing - especially if they want to report something inappropriate.

Actually the "Privacy Policy" and "Legal" links should probably be higher up too.

Comment: expand the bottom of the page with enough padding to accommodate the banner that's getting in the way.

Comment: @KevinB that works too. It doesn't matter what the solution is, the "contact us" link shouldn't be hidden.

Comment: The recent blog post debacle got started because SO employees are fed-up with having to deal with the nastygrams they get through the Contact Us link.  What is the game-plan here, you want to toughen them up with more of it?  Feature, not a bug.